# algebraic Modulo question

Tags: polynomials

What are the following $\text{unknown}_1$ and $\text{unknown}_2$?
as I find that 
$$\frac{x^2y-xy^3+2y^2-2}{6x^2y-5x^2-xy^3+7y^2+13} = \text{a constant}$$
but use this constant can not find back the rem result.

it is for calculating modulo
http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~zca/Reports_on_ca/02/paper_html/node27.html

actually I want to know where do $\text{unknown}_1$ and $\text{unknown}_2$ come from?

formula = $\theta_m(a) = \mathrm{rem}(a, \text{m})$;  but software can not calculate when m is a constant, if m is not a constant, what do m represent ?

$$P = 6x^2y-5x^2-xy^3+7y^2+13$$

$\theta_5(P) = \mathrm{rem}(P, \text{unknown}_1)$;

$\theta_5(P) = \mathrm{rem}(6x^2y-5x^2-xy^3+7y^2+13,\text{unknown}_1) = x^2y-xy^3+2y^2-2$

$\theta_7(P) = \mathrm{rem}(P, \text{unknown}_2)$;

$\theta_7(P) = \mathrm{rem}(6x^2y-5x^2-xy^3+7y^2+13,\text{unknown}_2) = -x^2y+2x^2-xy^3-1$

updated:
software using http://www.mmrc.iss.ac.cn/mmp/
i guess maple has similar function

i do not understand a chinese book's writing, not mentioning above unknown, only said coefficient

is the following command to reduce the coefficient module 5 , but it is the result of above which coefficient to redcue?
rem(6*x^2*y-5*x^2-x*y^3+7*y^2+13,pmod(6*x^2*y-5*x^2-x*y^3+7*y^2+13,5));

and why use 5 and 7 ? where do these integer come from?

i find a statement divide each coefficient by q and take the remainder
but type command according to this statement is not correct
rem(6*x^2*y-5*x^2-x*y^3+7*y^2+13, quo(6*x^2*y-5*x^2-x*y^3+7*y^2+13, 5));

Comment: Please make the question self-contained.  What are $\text{unknown}_1,\text{unknown}_2$ and the rem result?  What software are you using?

Comment: updated software using, Maple have similar function

Comment: What is the difference between $\theta_m(a)$ and $a \pmod{m}$?

Comment: I guess the same, but it is written in another style, why m = 5 and m = 7,do it choose coefficient of -5*x^2 and 7*y^2, why negative sign not considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that unknown1 is 5 and unknown2 is 7. If you reduce the coefficients of $6x^2y-5x^2-xy^3+7y^2+13$ modulo 5, you get $x^2y-xy^3+2y^2-2$, and similarly for the other example.

Comment: how to reduce coefficient modulo 5? which coefficient to reduce ? i updated the command above,but result is not the same

Comment: $6x^2y-5x^2-xy^3+7y^2+13$ is congruent to $x^2y-xy^3+2y^2-2$ modulo 5, because the difference between the two expressions is $5(x^2y-x^2+y^2+3)$, a multiple of 5. All the coefficients are reduced, and it looks like they are reduced to being between $-2$ and $2$.